# How to change the package name of an Android flavor app with Gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-productflavors

I am currently migrating a very old Android app from Eclipse to Android Studio.

In the old version of my app, I was able to create some "flavors" with an Ant script. The aim of this script was to do a copy of the Eclipse project with a different package name and with different resources (drawable, etc.)

I have migrated the project to Android Studio, deleted the Ant script and created some flavors.

But now, I have some issues to deserialize - in the new version of the app - an object serialized in the old version of the app.

Here a part of the stackstrace : `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.app.flavor.bo.Player`

In the old version, each flavors had it own package name :

- `com.company.app`
- `com.company.app.flavor`

In this new version, the code structure is `com.company.app.flavor` and I play with Gradle in order to generate the good `applicationId` for the flavor.

So, the `applicationId` for the flavor is correct, but the package name of the class seems to respect the project structure so, I cannot deserialize the original object with the package `com.company.app.flavor.bo.Player` into the object `com.company.app.bo.Player`.

If I change the structure of the project with `com.company.app.flavor` it will work for the flavor but not for the original one with the `applicationId` `com.company.app`.

So, is there a way, with Gradle or maybe another tool (proguard ?) to change the `applicationId` AND the package name for a flavor ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why you should change the package name in the flavor?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti : In order to deserialize the object :)

Comment: Ok but you can do it also with the original package. I don't understand the point.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can have ProductFlavor in gradle and this supposed to change the package name of the app. If you didn't hardcoded the classpath then serialization also should work without any issues.

```
      android {
          .
          .
          .
     defaultConfig {
            applicationId "lib4.com.stackoverflow"
        }

         productFlavors {
                staging {
                   applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
                }

                preProduction {

                    applicationIdSuffix ".preProduction"

                }
        }
  }
```

Once the apk got created, you can verify whether the package name has been changed or not by dragging and dropping apk on android studio and open Android Manifest. You will see the updated package name in the manifest in apk. But in source code, you will still see the package you provided earlier.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in my case. The applicationId is changed but the package name is not changed (I can see it in the stacktrace).

Comment: @rolandl I edited my answer. Please do analyze your apk using android studio.

Comment: In the manifest, the package has been updated with the new one. But in dex, the class is still referenced with `com.company.app.bo.Player` and not with `com.company.app.flavor.bo.Player`. That's the problem :(

Comment: It is not correct. the application ID and package name are independent of each other